# Suddenly scheduled tasks are not running in coldfusion 8

Tags: coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion MX8 server and one of the scheduled task was running from 2 years but now suddenly from 01/12/2014 scheduled tasks are not running. When i browsed the file in browser then the file is running successfully without error.

I am not sure is there any updatation or license expiration problem. I am aware that mid of this year Adobe closed the support for coldfusion 8.

Answer (score 1):

The first most common problem of this problem is *external* to the server. When you say you *browsed to the file* and it worked in a browser, it is very important to know if that test was performed on the *server desktop*. Knowing that you can browse to the file from *your* desktop or laptop is of small value.

The most common source of issues like this is a change in the DNS or network stack that is interfereing with resolution. For example, if the internal DNS serving your DMZ suddenly starts serving the "external" address - suddenly your *server* can't browse to your domain. Or if the IP served by the server for the domain in question goes from being 127.0.0.1 to some other IP that the server can't acces correctly due to reverse proxy or LB or some other rule. Finally, sometimes the Apache or IIS is altered so that an IP that previously was serviced (127.0.0.1 being the most common example) now does not respond.

If it is something intrinsic to the scheduler service then Frank's advice is pretty good - especially look for "proxy schduler" entries in the log - they can give you good clues. I would also log results of a scheduled task to a file. Then check the file. If it exists then your scheduled tasks ARE running - they are just not succeeding. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the cf scheduling service crash in CF8. The rest of CF is unaffected.

Have you tried restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

**Here are your concerns:**

- Your File (works since you tested it manually).
- Your Scheduled Task (failed).
- Your Coldfusion Application (Service) (any changes here)?
- Your Server (what about here).

To test your problem create a duplicate task and schedule it.  Leave the other one in place (maybe set your new one to run earlier). Use the same file too. See if it completes.

If it doesn't then you have a larger problem. Since the Coldfusion Server sits atop of the JVM there could be something happening there. Things just don't stop working unless something got corrupted or you got compromised. If you hardened your server by rearranging/renaming the file structure to make it more secure...It would break your task.

**So going back:** if your test schedule works then determine what is different between the two. Note you have logging capabilities. [Logging abilities for CF8](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=basiconfig_20.html)

If you are not directly incharge of maintaining this server, then I would recommend asking around and see if there was recent maintenance, if so, what was done to the server?

Comment: Hey Frank! nice to see you on here.

Comment: @MarkAKruger Yes sir! :) You are the CF/Server Guru :) I am sure you could knock this answer out of the park...